# How to make image in html transparent?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have a html file and I want to put an image in. The image should be transparent. The way I am doing now - first comes the image, and after it finishes, there comes the text and the other images. How to add transparent image in html?
This is my code now:

```
<img src="result_files\image003.png" alt="some_text"/>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using `opacity` (and `filter` for IE).

```
<img src="result_files\image003.png" alt="some_text" style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);"/>
```

Now, I understand your question, the answer is something like this:

```
 <div style="background:url(image.jpg)"> the content here </div>
```

Comment: This only makes the image brighter. I want to make it visible, but to put images/text ON it.

Comment: So, I didn't understand you question. Opacity is THE way to make images transparent in html.

Comment: But I want the image to be some kind of background for the content.

Comment: So, your question is other.

Try doing something like this: <div style="background:url(image.jpg)"> the content here </div>

Comment: Can't believe no one else has upvoted an accepted answer which took 2 iterations of understanding the question. The question actually has nothing to do with transparency at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property opacity or just make the png transparent in an image editor.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the image be the background, should be

HTML

```
<div class="content">
...content...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
background-image:url('imageurl.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make it transparent, paste this into your javascript and edit as you please.

```html
 <a href="http://www.hlgjyl888.com/data/wallpapers/30/WDF_780770.png"><img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="http://www.hlgjyl888.com/data/wallpapers/30/WDF_780770.png" style="position:fixed; right:10px; bottom:20px; width:80px; height:80px; border:none; cursor:pointer; background:none;"></a>

 <script>
  function bigImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "120px";
  x.style.width = "120px";
  x.style.opacity = "0.2";
 }

  function normalImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "80px";
  x.style.width = "80px";
  x.style.opacity = "100";
  }
 </script>
```

`x.style.opacity` tells the browser to set the opacity, if copying this to your document there are a few more things you should know...

`style="position:fixed; right:10px; bottom:20px;` Positions it at bottom right         of page.

`cursor:pointer;` Makes the cursor stay pointer on all or almost all browsers.

Hope this helps you!